MySQL package dependency issue
I've recently migrated a personal server to a new VM running 20.04. I initially needed MySQL 5.7 on this system, because that's what I had on my old 18.04 system and I couldn't upgrade MySQL there. So I followed the instructions at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/ to install 5.7, then copied over my database, finished my migration, all was well. Then, following the same instructions, I upgraded to MySQL 8.0 by running sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-apt-config etc. That worked fine.
However, now I want to upgrade to the next Ubuntu LTS. When I run apt update and then apt upgrade I get:
The following packages have been kept back:
  mysql-common
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.

So it seems like I need to fix this issue with mysql-common before I can proceed. I tried to upgrade it explicitly:
root@carlton:~# apt install mysql-common
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libcgi-fast-perl libcgi-pm-perl libevent-core-2.1-7 libevent-pthreads-2.1-7 libfcgi-perl libhtml-template-perl libmecab2 mecab-ipadic mecab-ipadic-utf8 mecab-utils
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  mysql-client mysql-client-8.0 mysql-client-core-8.0 mysql-server mysql-server-8.0 mysql-server-core-8.0
The following packages will be upgraded:
  mysql-common
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 6 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 66.8 kB of archives.
After this operation, 260 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]

No, I don't want you to remove all my other mysql packages - why do you want to do that? I am starting to think that mysql-common is an Ubuntu package that I installed in the very beginning, before realizing that I needed MySQL 5.7 and installed the MySQL project packages. I see that it only provides some /etc/mysql structure and default files, which are also provided by mysql-server-8.0. So I thought I could just remove mysql-common, but again it wants to remove all the other mysql packages too. I tried dpkg --remove mysql-common and apt-get remove mysql-common without any luck. Here is the current state:
root@carlton:~# dpkg -l | grep mysql
ii  mysql-apt-config                      0.8.29-1                                   all          Auto configuration for MySQL APT Repo.
ii  mysql-client                          8.0.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1                    all          MySQL database client (metapackage depending on the latest version)
ii  mysql-client-8.0                      8.0.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1                    amd64        MySQL database client binaries
ii  mysql-client-core-8.0                 8.0.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1                    amd64        MySQL database core client binaries
ri  mysql-common                          5.8+1.0.5ubuntu2                           all          MySQL database common files, e.g. /etc/mysql/my.cnf
ic  mysql-community-server                5.7.42-1ubuntu18.04                        amd64        MySQL Server
ii  mysql-server                          8.0.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1                    all          MySQL database server (metapackage depending on the latest version)
ii  mysql-server-8.0                      8.0.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1                    amd64        MySQL database server binaries and system database setup
ii  mysql-server-core-8.0                 8.0.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1                    amd64        MySQL database server binaries

Looking for suggestions on how to proceed. Thanks!
EDIT: Per comments below, I uninstalled all mysql packages, and then I was able to upgrade successfully. I am now on 22.04. But I had more issues trying to reinstall mysql:
owen@carlton ~$ sudo apt install mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-common : Conflicts: mysql-server-8.0 but 8.0.39-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 is to be installed
 mysql-server-8.0 : Depends: mysql-client-8.0 (>= 8.0.39-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) but it is not installable
                    Depends: mysql-server-core-8.0 (= 8.0.39-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

I kept getting this, even when I had completely purged mysql-common all other mysql packages. It was very strange, dpkg -l showed no mysql packages at all, but this error persisted. I then installed mysql-common again, but the error remained. I had no extra mysql package sources in my source.list files. Finally I did apt remove mysql-common again, and then suddenly apt install mysql-server worked.
The only explanation I have is that the MySQL project apt package was screwing things up somehow (and maybe providing its own mysql-common, I don't know). Anyway I am back in business now.

The mysql-common which has been kept back and therefore not upgraded is preventing you from upgrading from Ubuntu 20.04 to Ubuntu 22.04. When you try to remove the mysql-common package with sudo apt remove mysql-common it requires you to remove several other mysql packages too. This is not such a bad situation. Save a list of all the packages that removing mysql-common would also remove and remove all of them. Then the upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04 can proceed normally.
After the upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04 is completely check that everything is working normally. Now you can install the mysql-common package and other mysql packages that you removed in order to upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04. The following MySQL 8.0 packages are currently installed in your Ubuntu 20.04. Start off by installing them with these commands.
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install mysql-client-8.0 mysql-client-core-8.0 mysql-server-8.0 mysql-server-core-8.0 mysql-client mysql-server

You can safely remove mysql-common after upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04 if you no longer need it.
mysql-client and mysql-server packages are compatible with MySQL 8.0 in Ubuntu 22.04. mysql-common on the other hand is specific to MySQL 5.8 in Ubuntu 20.04 and Ubuntu 22.04. Check if MySQL 8.0 which you installed is working normally before proceeding further.

From the author's edit to the main question:

I kept getting this, even when I had completely purged mysql-common
all other mysql packages. It was very strange, dpkg -l showed no
mysql packages at all, but this error persisted. I then installed
mysql-common again, but the error remained. I had no extra mysql
package sources in my source.list files. Finally I did apt remove mysql-common again, and then suddenly apt install mysql-server
worked.
The only explanation I have is that the MySQL project apt package was
screwing things up somehow (and maybe providing its own mysql-common,
I don't know). Anyway I am back in business now.


Assuming you've upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 successfully and installed mysql-client-8.0 and mysql-server-8.0 successfully, you might want to comment and update me about what you plan to try to install next.

I guess I just was trying to avoid having to uninstall all of mysql, install it again, and restore my DB. This seems like a lot of work just to get around the mysql-common issue. "mysql-common on the other hand is specific to MySQL 5.8 in Ubuntu 20.04 and Ubuntu 22.04." Right, so I already have MySQL 8.0 packages installed from the official MySQL repos, and it seems I no longer need mysql-common. Can't I just get rid of it? I suppose I can force purge it but I wasn't sure if that was wise.

You can safely remove mysql-common after upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04 if you no longer need it. Uninstalling the broken packages in order to pave the way to a successful release upgrade will save you lots of time in the long run.

Thanks, I was able to upgrade but then ran into more problems with the mysql packages. I eventually sorted them out - see my EDIT in the original post.
